# is there anything like implode for arrays of arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, implode

I understand implode works like this:

```
$array = array('value', 'value2');
echo implode(',', $array) // Gives you: value, value2
```

I have an array that looks like this:

```
$array = array(
    array('admin_options' => 'test'),
    array('test_options' => 'test'),
)
```

I want to do the exact same thing as implode **BUT** the out put should look like this:

```
array,array
```

The reason for this is because I can pass these two arrays, comma separated, into a function or class where the parameters are arrays.

So in an exmple:

if I have the following class:

```
class Test{
    public function __construct(array $options, array $second_options){}
}
```

Then what I should be looking at is essentially:

```
public function __construct(array, array){}
```

**Note:**

This same function should work if I have an array that looks like:

```
$array = array(
    array('admin_options' => 'test'),
    array('test_options' => 'test'),
    some_param,
    some_other_param
)
```

My out put should then be:

```
array, array, some_param, some_other_param
```

I hope this helps clarify my question.

I know that if I try and use implode I will get illegal string conversion of array. Thats why I need a function similar too it.

Comment: fixed to reflect that it is php.

Comment: loop through and merge then implode.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this would work:

```
$count = 0;
foreach($multiDimArray AS $name=>$value) {
    $varName = 'array'.$count++;
    $$varName = array("name"=>$value);
}
```

I haven't run this yet to check the syntax, but this should yield several array variables named $array0, etc. with the same values as each entry in the multi-dimensional array.

Comment: this is wrong, all you did here was merge the two arrays and give it a key of name. not what I wanted. The end result should be: 'array, array'

Comment: I think I understand now, but how do you intend to pass the resulting string to that function? I don't think it will work like that. function("array, array") is only 1 parameter and it won't be readable unless you parse it again within the function.